# Pro.5 sec.3.2 in kreyszngs "introductory Functional analysis with application

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show that for a sequence $(x_n)$ in an inner product space the conditions $\lVert x_n \rVert \to \lVert x \rVert$ and $\langle x_n,x \rangle \to \langle x, x\rangle$ imply convergence $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$\|x_n-x\|^{2}=\|x_n\|^{2}-2\Re \langle x_n, x \rangle +\|x\|^{2}\to \|x\|^{2}-2\|x\|^{2}+\|x\|^{2}=0$.